# How to take multiple string value as input?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I have a string variable that I use to get input values. for ex.

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in); 
varName=in.next();
```

when I give value as (John jony) it only displays John. Any way to get whole string?

Comment: Hint: do some research. There are tons and tons and tons of questions and tutorials how to use that scanner thing. And beyond that: Please take the time to properly format your questions. That preview function; and all the help around the edit window ... are there for a reason!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instead:

```
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in); 
    String text = in.nextLine();        
    System.out.println( text );
```

"in.nextLine()" reads in a whole line